# Brain Metrix Free IQ test question - dots and slashes in a 2x2 grid

Tags: pattern, visual

This question comes from Brain Metrix's free IQ test(http://www.brainmetrix.com/free-iq-test/). This is the question:
[image]

I know that the answer is either option A or option C but I do not know whether it is A or C. I did find out a pattern of how the stick (the /) moves but I do not know how the dots move. I am also puzzled where by in the first and second pictures, there are 2 dots but in the third picture, there is only one. I do not know whether there is a mistake in the question or is there a pattern that explains why one dot disappeared and how the dots move. Any help in this puzzle is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is probably

> C

because

> The stick keeps alternating between one pair of opposite corners. One of the dots does the same, starting in the bottom right. The other dot moves clockwise around the square, starting at the top left. In the third picture the two dots coincide, so it looks like only one dot.